# How does an encryption key work?

Tags: encryption, cryptography

I'm having trouble understanding how an encryption key works.

for example: if the word was 'hello' its encrypted value could be 'GHSSDgsd2', what would happen to the encrypted value if the key was 'dog'? how would it change the encrypted value of 'hello'?